# how to access a child element dynamically in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF, I have a structure like this

```
<Button>
    <Grid>
        <!--definitions for 1 row and 2 columns-->
        <TextBlock x:Name="t1" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="t2" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

Supposed a `Button b` with this structure is generated dynamically. How to access `t1` from `Button b`?

Edit for clarification: Since `t1` resides within `Button b`, is it possible to change the content of `t1` if one only have access to `b`? something along the line of `b.childGridElement.childTextBlock_t1.Text = "newString"`?

Comment: the button needs to "access" a textblock? what does that mean?

Comment: Use `ElementName` bindings.

Comment: `(b.Content as Grid).Children.OfType<TextBox>().First(x => x.Name == "t1").Text = "newString";` but this is not the way `WPF` is designed to work, if you want to change the `Text` of `t1` bind it to a `string` property

Comment: If you know/have control over the naming of the dynamically created elements, you can use FindName to get the textblock, cast it, and then set its text property.

Comment: @sa true. I am new to WPF and have been resisting "binding" and "MVVM" so far. doesn't seem to be a wise decision as my code is getting uglier everyday. I know there are many resources online, but is there one you would recommend for beginner regarding binding and some other key stuff in WPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for the use case you've provided:

`((TextBlock)b.FindName("t1")).Text = "newString";`

Comment: thanks for the reply, but b is a `Button` which contains a `Grid`.

Comment: yes, but the above solution works. have you tried implementing and check the outcome?

Comment: FindName will search all descendants of the element upon which it is called. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `b.FindName("t1")` returns null. I set the name by using `TextBlock t = new TextBlock(); t.Name="t1"`. anyting wrong with this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Visual Tree Helper for this.

Define Handler Extension Method

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            if (parent != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
                {
                    var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);

                    // If the available child is not null and is of required Type<T> then return with this child else continue this loop
                    if (child != null && child is T)
                    {
                        yield return (T)child;
                    }

                    foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                    {
                        yield return childOfChild;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

now in your xaml

```
IEnumerable<TextBlock> textblockes=FindVisualChildren<TextBlock>(b);

foreach (var textblock in textblockes)
{
  if (textblock!= null && textblock.Name="t1")
  {
    //write code for t1 here;
  }
  if (textblock!= null && textblock.Name="t2")
  {
    //write code for t2 here;
  }                                     

}
```

In above method whatever is your tree structure , it will find all the textblock of your  Button b and then on the basis of Name property you can do appropriate operations.